# JS при клике тогглит класс не тому блоку

Tags: javascript, html, css

написал HTML, CSS, и к нему JS код к одной секции, при клике по блоку у него должен тогглиться класс, но он отглится у дочернего блока, а не у того, по которому кликнули, что очень странно... Ниже приложу код:

```html
<section class="section questions">
            <div class="container">
                <h2 class="title">Остались вопросы?</h2>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="questions__item">
                        <h3 class="questions__title">Какие отличия между Mavic 2 Pro и Mavic 2 Zoom?</h3>
                        <p class="questions__text">В Mavic 2 улучшены практически все аспекты: камера, передача видеосигнала, полётное время, скорость, уровень шума, обнаружение препятствий в нескольких направлениях, интеллектуальные функции и уникальная функция Hyperlapse (гиперлапс).</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="questions__item">
                        <h3 class="questions__title">Чем Mavic 2 лучше Mavic Pro?</h3>
                        <p class="questions__text">В Mavic 2 улучшены практически все аспекты: камера, передача видеосигнала, полётное время, скорость, уровень шума, обнаружение препятствий в нескольких направлениях, интеллектуальные функции и уникальная функция Hyperlapse (гиперлапс).</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="questions__item">
                        <h3 class="questions__title">Можно ли подключить Mavic 2 к очкам DJI Goggles?</h3>
                        <p class="questions__text">В Mavic 2 улучшены практически все аспекты: камера, передача видеосигнала, полётное время, скорость, уровень шума, обнаружение препятствий в нескольких направлениях, интеллектуальные функции и уникальная функция Hyperlapse (гиперлапс).</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="questions__item">
                        <h3 class="questions__title">Является ли Mavic 2 водонепроницаемым？</h3>
                        <p class="questions__text">В Mavic 2 улучшены практически все аспекты: камера, передача видеосигнала, полётное время, скорость, уровень шума, обнаружение препятствий в нескольких направлениях, интеллектуальные функции и уникальная функция Hyperlapse (гиперлапс).</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

```css
.questions {
    &__item {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.30);
        padding: 22px 10px 22px 40px;
        max-width: 762px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        ::after {
            content: url('../images/questions__item-arrow.svg');
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    &__title {
        @extend %ubuntu-medium;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: 132.135%;
        max-width: 510px;
    }
    &__text {
        @extend %ubuntu-light;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 130%;
        max-width: 640px;
        display: none;
    }
    &__item--active .questions__item-text {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

```js
const questions__item = document.querySelectorAll('.questions__item');

questions__item.forEach((e) => {
    e.addEventListener('click', (el) => {
        el.target.classList.toggle('questions__item--active');
    });
})
```

Вот скриншот кому он тогглит класс O_o[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверное потому что при клике `el.target` -- заголовок, потому вместо `el.target.classList.toggle('questions__item--active');` делайте `e.classList.toggle('questions__item--active');`

Comment: А как сделать, чтоб questions__item, по которому я жму тогглился?

Comment: Отредактировал комментарий.

Comment: Спасибо! А теперь другой вопрос, у меня не работает &__item--active .questions__item-text {
        display: block;
    }, класс тогглится, все хорошо, но дисплей блок не работает на текст, родитель которого имеет класс __item--active

Comment: В разметке у Вас просто `questions__text`, там нет такого класса как `questions__item-text`.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!